# Why does code with the OpenMP library run longer in parallel mode than in sequential mode?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a problem with using omp.h library.The task was to create and test an algorithm for solving equations using the Gaussian method using examples with a large number of equations (from 500).The difference in execution time in serial and parallel modes should be visible. My code shows 1.140253 sec in serial mode and 4.394211 sec in parallel mode. I don't understand where is mistake

I use this in code for parallel mode, and when i need serial I uncomment line with omp_set_num_threads(1)

```
//omp_set_num_threads(1);
for (k = 0; k \< N - 1; k++)
{

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = k + 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            
            d = A[i][k] / A[k][k];
            
            for (j = k; j < N; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = A[i][j]- d * A[k][j];
            }
            B[i] = B[i] - d * B[k];
        }
    }
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <omp.h>

const int N = 1000;
double A[N][N]; 
double B[N];    
double E[N];    

using namespace std;

void gauss(double A[N][N], double B[N], double E[N])
{
    
    int i, j, k;
    double d;
    //omp_set_num_threads(1);
    for (k = 0; k < N - 1; k++)
    {
        
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = k + 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            
            d = A[i][k] / A[k][k];
            
            for (j = k; j < N; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = A[i][j]- d * A[k][j];
            }
            B[i] = B[i] - d * B[k];
        }
    }
    
    for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        E[i] = B[i];
        
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            E[i] = E[i] - A[i][j] * E[j];
        }
        E[i]= E[i]/A[i][i];
    }
};

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            A[i][j] = -10 + rand() % 20;
        }
        B[i] = -10 + rand() % 20;
        
    }
    
    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    gauss(A, B, E);

    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    
    cout << "Time: " << fixed << (end - start) << " sec" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `d` and `j` variables are shared so threads step on each other's toes when they write to them. Declare them inside the parallelized loop

Comment: One golden rule of programming is to declare variables close to their used (so to avoid mistakes like this and improve readability). Another golden rule is to *check results* before measuring performance. Bogus programs can be much faster ;) .

Comment: By the way, please note that the operation is rather memory bound so the speed up should be small even with an efficient correct code. On top of that, there is a work imbalance between threads due to the inner loop. The slowest thread limit the scalability of the code.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I think the workload is balanced, here, as k is kept constant within the parallel region.

Comment: @PierU Indeed. I read to quickly the code. Sorry.

Comment: Side-note: Your first instinct should be to compare the results to the known-good serial version. In my experience poor performance correlates strongly with invalid results because these types of error cause both.